# HTTP Request works in postman but doesn't work in code

Tags: c#, httprequest, postman

I'm trying to access a website that requires login via a form.
I used the Postman HTTP client.

I tried to do the normally http post request but didn't seem to work, I get a successful status code (200 OK) but it doesn't log in, eventually did work with a GET request with BODY parameters (I hadn't seen GET request with body parameters).
Well, I tried to simulate this request in C# code with no luck, I even tried the generated code that Postman offers with no luck again.
Down below is the Postman request and the C# code snippet based on auto-generated Postman code. Does anyone know if is there to make this request with any library or if there is something that I miss?

Thank you in advance.

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://thessalia-3.teilar.gr/login.asp");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddHeader("Referer", "https://thessalia-3.teilar.gr/login.asp");

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        parameters["userName"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("myusername");
        parameters["pwd"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("mypass");
        parameters["loginTrue"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("extravalue");

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", content);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
```

[Postman Request Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MshnY.png)

**Edit:**

[Postman Request Body Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DawLN.png)

I've also tried to run this but also not logged in.
[Auto-generated code form Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7iqD.png)

Comment: Saying *"didn't seem to work"* is not very helpful. Check the error that your getting the browser and add it to your question so we can help you better. Now, are you sure the page you're trying to post to allows CORS? Also, why are you serializing your parameters to JSON if you're posting them as form parameters?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Did you get any error?

Comment: @ipinak Yeah sorry about that, I meant that the login was unsuccessful instead of Postman where there the login was completely successful.
The request itself is successful and returns 200 OK status code but it doesn't login properly.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't login properly? Do you get any error?

Comment: @RacilHilan I don't know if allows CORS and I don't know where can I check that, but if Postman get successfully log in, I suppose it allows CORS. As for json parameters just tried something that I read, as you can see I've edited my question and you can see the auto generated postman code that didn't logged in too.

Comment: @ipinak I got the HTML result page that appears when your log in credentials are not correct.

Comment: If the request was successful (200) and you got the HTML page for "Invalid Credentials", then your code that's making the request should be fine and the issue is with the credentials. Like I said in my first comment, don't serialize the parameters to JSON. URL-encode them instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the request was successful (200) and you got the HTML page for "Invalid Credentials", then your code that's making the request should be fine and the issue is with the credentials. Like I said in my first comment, don't serialize the parameters to JSON, URL-encode them instead:

```
parameters["userName"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("myusername");
parameters["pwd"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("mypass");
parameters["loginTrue"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("extravalue");
```

This is the standard way and it works with writing the parameters directly to the request stream, or with a utility class like `StringContent`. However, since you're using the utility class `FormUrlEncodedContent`, it URL-encode them for you, so you don't have to. In that case, simply assign them directly as string:

```
parameters["userName"] = "myusername";
parameters["pwd"] = "mypass";
parameters["loginTrue"] = "extravalue";
```

Comment: Unfortunately even this didn't work, I got exactly the same response. I think there is something that I miss..

Comment: Then I'm afraid that we will need the credentials to help you. Do you have a set of test credentials that you can share with us. Or you can change the password to some dumb password to share it with us and then change it back when we find the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any set of test credentials. But I think I can change the password. I will let you know when I do that.